# Want to fetch the data's from JSON file and place it in the respective place?

Tags: android

- I can able to fetch the name of the restaurant using id from the json file and show it in this page.
- My Doubt is :If we click the “Annalakshmi restaurant”(i.e ,id=1) then it must fetch all the data’s from json with the id=1 and fill the other details of that id to the next page which contains phone number,address....I have to fill the details about that restaurants,we have to fetch from JSON. And at the top i have to keep the images of that restaurant.

My json is:

```
{
  "Categories": {
  "restaurant": 
   {
   "res_id": "1",
    "res_name": "Annalakshmi Restaurant",
    "res_phone":"92600 18001",
    "res_time": "12-3PM,7-9PM - Monday(Closed)"
     },
    {
    "res_id": "2",
    "res_name": "Kaidi Kitchen",
    "res_phone":"090213 37222",
    "res_time":"12-3PM,7-10.30PM (All Day)"
  },
    {
    "res_id":"3",``
    "res_name":"TajCoromandel",
    "res_phone":"044 6600 2827",
  "res_time":"24 Hours(All day)"
  }
   ]
```

Comment: You can insert this json data in database and then fetch data  by Select query by "res_id".

Comment: How do you read this json data ?
If you map each "Restaurant" to a Restaurant class, with id, name, phone attributes, you can store it in a HashMap with id as key

Comment: First you have to parse the data then store it in any collection array and then use it or best way is to store it in database and then simply use it.

Comment: you can store it in objects maybe this would help http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/